# Does jQuery load() send any data even when the requested element is not found?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I have a code like this:

```
   $('#intro-posts-container').load('/ajax/load.php', function() {
      bindVoting();
   });
```

Does the load send the request to load.php, if the `#intro-posts-container` element doesn't exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick test in firebug on this page shows that it *does not* send the request if the element doesn't exist.

I've verified this from the [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js) (v1.8.3), which contains the following:

```
jQuery.fn.load = function( url, params, callback ) {
    // [snip]

    // Don't do a request if no elements are being requested
    if ( !this.length ) {
        return this;
    }

    // [snip]
}
```

Comment: Wow people in the jQuery team even thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't send any request since the element never gets loaded itself the event is never triggered